# WPF Validation on textbox only on buttonclick not on windowload

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, idataerrorinfo

I am new to WPF, I have a simple login window implemented in MVVM with loginname/password and a button.

My view-model implements the interface `IDataErrorInfo` to validate `TextBox`es.

My intention is to have empty `TextBox`es on load and on click on `login` button, validate `TextBox`es and show validation errors (e.g. name field is empty).

These are the bindings I defined:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName"
  Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"
/>
```

With a style for `ToolTip` errors:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:StaticRelativeSource.Self},
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
        />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I implemented the `this`-property of `IDataErrorInfo` with validations in the view-model as so:

```
public string this(string columnName)
{
    get
    {
       return Validate(columnName);
    }
}
```

I am binding the view-model to the data-context class object.
It works as expected except that an error is shown in `TextBox` on window-load and not only when login is clicked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Mode=TwoWay` and also change the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Try code below.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName"
  Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
  Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"
/>
```

Also you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and trigger the event `PropertyChanged` on the string property in viewmodel.